# play multiple media element in windows phone 7 silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have multiple mediaElement and multiple buttons to play each, however , each time al play the different media element though they have different source

how to play the different ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to play multiple elements at once you need to use the SoundEffect class from XNA.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use multiple MediaElements - just use a single one and wire up the different playback controls to it.

If you hit the play button when another source is playing, stop and reset the MediaElement to the new required source.